# Grinder - recording script seems to have no effect

Tags: grinder

I'm attempting to record a script using the following command.

```
java net.grinder.TCPProxy -console -http > grinderTest.py
```

It appears to work (as in while the proxy is recording I can visit the web pages), but when I stop it, nothing has been output to `grinderTest.py`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if someone else searches this, this can be caused if you are testing with a server on your localhost. When you have a proxy and localhost destination make sure that the proxy settings do not bypass the localhost target (preferences\network\settings in FireFox).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Answer pulled from OP*</sup>

Something on classpath was causing grinder to throw an error before writing to the file.

Reducing the classpath to only include `grinder.jar` solved the issue.